# all actions / comments should keep track of comments versed into chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find the `all actions / comments` list (on the user's profile: `https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/$userId/$userName?tab=activity&sort=comments`) useful since one is not necessarily notified personally when other comments are added to some post one has commented in the past.

This list is just an easy way for me to check.

OKOK, I know that I could just bookmark the question however… it just (frequently) happens that I am not that much interested in the post I commented but much more in the comments it might triggered.

I noticed that many clever contributors use comments for questioning. And this just opens my mind much more than whatever question/answer would.

It happens that the number of comments increases too quickly for my sample rate… so much that, all of a sudden, they'll all be versed into the obscure darkness of some lost anonymous chatroom.

As an immediate consequence of this, any trace of my comment as part of the `all actions/comments` list will just vanish. Too bad! I'll have to resort to the search engine keying  apropxitamteliy what I could vaguely remember about OP's question.

< kidding > Not to say that all commenters, not to say me in particular, will have incidentally & almost certainly lost an occasion to get that very rare *pundit* badge. < /kidding >

I would therefore suggest that, in case of comments moved into some chatroom, the all `actions / comments` list keeps track of them with an http link to the chatroom all comments went moved to. Keeping the first words of the comment as a label would be great but changing it to the label of the chatroom would be just fine.

Comment: Any update to allow tracking of comments would be viewed favorably by me!  I think comments are useful (meta?)data and should be kept somewhere findable.